# Entity Framework MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table already exists

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have been facing an issue while running EF command Update-Database in Package Manager Console.
Below is the error I received please help me to resolve it.

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'tablename' already exists

Answer (score 1):

By removing your previous migration that creates the table 'Student' EntityFramework now is generating the migration with a Create Table Script, if you want to remove a migration you must revert it from your database aswell. Now you can either recreate your database or revert/delete the 'Students' table on your database.

try to Run the

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

command in Package Manager Console. This creates an empty migration with the current model as a snapshot. and then Run the

```
Update-Database
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
There is no database exist. Actually, I was trying to create database with respective tables and data after running the migration file. 
But while running the update-Database I came across the issue "Table exists already ".
I also deleted all the existing migration files and recreated new migration files by running Add-Migration fileName, ran update-Database but still same issue occured.
I also tried as you suggested but I got an error at -IgnoreChanges